# Simple Maven pom.xml fails

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3

Am new to Maven, running Eclipse Neon, m2e plugin Maven 3.3.9
this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.biscom.fa</groupId>
    <artifactId>FA_Bean</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</project>
```

generates this error, when saving it

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project XX_Bean'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
More errors follow
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the firewall. Was not allowing to contact central maven repository. Once i fixed this issue and downloaded the necessary files wverything started to work.